# Multiple versions of source files in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I was wondering if it would be possible to save different versions of a particular file in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. Let's say that I want to change a major part of my project. I know that the current version of my project is running fine, but I want to make some change and then compare the two versions of the program. I want to be able to save multiple versions of a C++ source/header file and then use the desired version according to my needs. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Devjeet

Comment: Make a copy of the file you want to change and name it something different. Then create two build profiles, one which compiles one version, and another which compiles the other.

Comment: There are things like version control programs which can do this for the whole project. See for example git, cvs, or some other tool like that...

Comment: Oh,yeah, that's what I do right now. I was wondering if there was a more streamlined approach to it as compared to renaming or  backup/restore, like if there was an inbuilt feature

Comment: @devjeetroy Visual Studio has tools built-in for working with revision control.  Out of the box, it has hooks for TFS, but you can also use the built-in tooling with other systems (ie: I use it with Mercurial...)

Comment: I think the tool for this is called a [DVCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Version_Control_System), with emphasis on the D for this case ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers. I found Mercurial, seems nice. Just one thing. Does mercurial save change history in a persistent fashion? like suppose I need to look at a version of my file from last week, would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to save multiple versions of a C++ source/header file and then use the desired version according to my needs. Is this possible?

This is really a job for version control.  I would recommend looking into a [revision control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for revision control software.
See:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software

Answer (score 1):

There is a property for source files to exclude a source from a particular build.
With that you for instance exclude a source from release-build and include it for debug-build.
You can extend that for extra (user-defined) build-types.

example: create an extra build-type (with configuration manager) with both a release and debug build for it, where you exclude the original source(s). then create the different source you want to change and include those in the project and make sure that those are exluded from the original builds. You need to use different names for those changed sources (preserving the originals).